# Remove preferred DNS from Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have set a preferred DNS on a VM connected via RDP and of course, now I cannot connect at all to that machine. Is there any way to remove it from the portal or is there any other way to do this? Thanks.

**Edit**:

I got an error trying to reset the configuration only.

> VM 'ImperialVM' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions.
>   Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish
>   outbound connections to Azure storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a crazy thing and it worked. Apparently, if you copy your VHD from one container to another, somehow the network configuration is lost, so was my DNS. Using Azure Explorer, it took like 2 seconds to copy it, a 127 GB VHD.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the portal to reset the RDP connection settings for a given Azure VM.

Select your VM in the Azure portal. Scroll down the settings pane to the Support + Troubleshooting section near the bottom of the list. Click the 'Reset password' button. Set the Mode to Reset configuration only and then click the Update button:

[image: Reset Azure VM RDP]

Per [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-connection).

Comment: In that case, there are a number of additional troubleshooting steps to try in the link I posted, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-connection; for example you could reset the NIC. I would try each troubleshooting step separately and try to reconnect upon completing each.

Answer (score 0):

If you have change DNS on the OS level the only option is to reset the NIC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-network-interface#reset-network-interface